# Remove "/page/1" from the URL

Tags: url-rewriting, pagination, rewrite-rules

The built-in permalinks in WordPress remove /page/1/ from the url of **first page** in the archives. However I added following custom rewrite rule

```
add_rewrite_rule('xxxx/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$','index.php?post_type=xxxx&page=$matches[1]','top');
```

It works fine but it does not remove the "/page/1/". How can I remove that from the URL with the rewrite rule?